# How to specify sorting data for QTableWidget

Tags: python, sorting, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget

When using the `QTableView` and a `QStandardItemModel`, you can specify a [`DataRole`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) to sort on via [`setSortRole`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html#setSortRole).

But `QTableWidget.model()` returns a `QAbsractItemModel`, which doesn't have the `setSortRole` method.

Is there a way when using `QTableWidget` to force the view to sort on a different data role than what is set as the text or display role data for the `QTableWidgetItem`?

Answer (score 2):

Re-implement the [less-than operator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#operator-lt) of the table-widget items:

```
class TableWidgetItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole) < other.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
```